# debuild: fatal error for ibm-watson-iot/device-raspberrypi source code

Tags: ibm-cloud, raspberry-pi3

I am using Raspberry Pi 3 with default image
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.59-v7+ #1047 SMP Sun Oct 29 12:19:23 GMT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux

I Cloned repository from github [ibmwatson-iot](https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/device-raspberrypi) and as per instruction installed required libs, tried to build with steps below

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ git clone https://github.com/ibm-messaging/iot-raspberrypi.git
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cd iot-raspberrypi/samples/c/
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev build-essential devscripts
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ debuild -b
```

Now I am getting linking error for crypto and ssl libs as below, what could be the problem?

```
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -uc -b
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: using a gain-root-command while being root
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source package iot
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source version 1.0-1
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source distribution unstable
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source changed by unknown jeffdare@in.ibm.com
dpkg-source --before-build c
dpkg-buildpackage: info: host architecture armhf
fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh clean
dh_testdir
dh_auto_clean
make -j1 clean
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/iot-raspberrypi/samples/c'
rm -f iot
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/iot-raspberrypi/samples/c'
dh_clean
debian/rules build
dh build
dh_testdir
dh_update_autotools_config
dh_auto_configure
dh_auto_build
make -j1
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/iot-raspberrypi/samples/c'
export LIBRARY_PATH=./lib:
cc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/pi/iot-raspberrypi/samples/c=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security iotmain.c cpustat.c mac.c mqttPublisher.c jsonator.c cJSON.c jsonReader.c -o iot -lpaho-mqtt3as -lpthread -lssl -lm -L ./lib -I .
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcrypto.so.1.0.0, needed by ./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.1.0.0, needed by ./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference to SSL_get_error@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference toSSL_CTX_load_verify_locations@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference to SSL_alert_desc_string_long@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference toSSL_CTX_set_msg_callback@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference to SSL_get1_session@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference toSSL_write@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference to CRYPTO_THREADID_set_numeric@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference toERR_get_error@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference to SSL_alert_type_string_long@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference toSSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference to SSL_CIPHER_get_name@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference toSSL_load_error_strings@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference to SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference toSSL_new@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference to CRYPTO_set_locking_callback@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference toOPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference to SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference toSSL_library_init@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference to SSL_get_current_cipher@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference toSSL_CTX_set_cipher_list@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference to SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference toSSL_shutdown@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference to SSL_connect@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference toSSL_get_cipher_list@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference to SSLv23_client_method@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference toSSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference to ERR_print_errors_fp@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference toSSL_CTX_set_info_callback@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference to SSL_set_session@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference toSSL_CTX_new@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference to CRYPTO_THREADID_set_callback@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference toCRYPTO_num_locks@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference to SSL_free@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference toSSL_read@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference to SSLeay_version@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference toERR_load_crypto_strings@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference to SSL_get_verify_result@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference toSSL_CTX_free@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference to SSL_CTX_ctrl@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference toSSL_pending@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference to SSL_CTX_set_verify@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference toSSL_state_string_long@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
./lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so: undefined reference to `SSL_set_fd@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:15: recipe for target 'iot' failed
make[1]: *** [iot] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/iot-raspberrypi/samples/c'
dh_auto_build: make -j1 returned exit code 2
debian/rules:13: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1116:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -uc -b failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Found Solution to this problem by recompiling the eclipse paho mqtt library [source code](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c)  on Raspberry Pi 3 and copied newly build libs in ibmwatson-iot source code folder 
Download eclipse paho mqtt [source code](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c) and follow steps give [here](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/c/) for linux.

Thank You